# NullPointerException в Activity

Tags: android

Почему выбрасывает исключение NullPointerException в `TextView stateInfo = findViewById(R.id.result);`?

Как я понимаю, это исключение генерируется, когда мы используем ссылочную переменную, в которой нету ссылки на конкретный объект в памяти. Получается `findViewById()` возвращает `null` вместо ссылки на объект, которому соответствует идентификатор `result`. Но я в XML прописал свойство `id` для этого объекта и этот идентификатор присутствует в `R`. Когда объявляю `stateInfo` не как поле класса, а как локальную переменную для обеих методов, то исключение не генерируется, что также непонятно. Прошу объяснить, почему так происходит. Заранее спасибо за помощь.
`activity_main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="@dimen/main_layout_padding"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.hfad.toggletesting.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/result"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/textView_hint"
        android:textSize="@dimen/textView_textSize"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="@dimen/textView_padding"/>

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggle_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/toggle_marginTop"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="@dimen/textView_textSize"
        android:textOn="@string/toggle_textOn"
        android:onClick="onClickToggleButton"
        android:textOff="@string/toggle_textOff"/>

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/switch_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/toggle_marginTop"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:onClick="onClickSwitch"
        android:textOn="@string/toggle_textOn"
        android:textOff="@string/toggle_textOff"/>



</LinearLayout>
```

`MainActivity.java`:

```
package com.hfad.toggletesting;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Switch;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView stateInfo = findViewById(R.id.result);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void onClickToggleButton(View view){
        ToggleButton toggleButton = findViewById(R.id.toggle_button);
        if (toggleButton.isChecked())
            stateInfo.setText(getString(R.string.textView_TextIfOnToggle));
        else
            stateInfo.setText(getString(R.string.textView_TextIfOffToggle));
    }

    public void onClickSwitch(View view){
        Switch switchButton = findViewById(R.id.switch_button);
        if(switchButton.isChecked())
            stateInfo.setText(getString(R.string.textView_TextIfOnSwitch));
        else
            stateInfo.setText(getString(R.string.textView_TextIfOffSwitch));
    }
}
```

`strings.xml`:

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">ToggleTesting</string>
    <string name="textView_hint">Current State</string>
    <string name="toggle_textOn">Light</string>
    <string name="toggle_textOff">Dark</string>
    <string name="textView_TextIfOnToggle">On in Toggle</string>
    <string name="textView_TextIfOffToggle">Off int Toggle</string>
    <string name="textView_TextIfOnSwitch">On in Switch</string>
    <string name="textView_TextIfOffSwitch">Off in Switch</string>
</resources>
```

`dimen.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="main_layout_padding">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="textView_textSize">30sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="textView_padding">14dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="toggle_marginTop">30dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Comment: `stateInfo = findViewById(R.id.result);` должно стоять после `setContentView()`

Comment: setContentView() есть же в onCreate(). Значит инициализация полей происходит до вызова метода onCreate()? Тогда получается, что когда мы инициализируем поле stateInfo, activity еще не известно ничего об layout, так как он указывается в setContentView(), а значит ничего неизвестно и об идентификаторе, значит findViewById возвращает null? Так ведь?

Comment: да, абсолютно верно